# How to create "Slide to Activate" in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, slider, gesture

I want to create Custom "Slide to Activate" view in my app. Apart from this does apple will approve this app which uses such component?

Image is given here
[image: SLIDER]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? According to Apple HIG everything is all right.

Upd.
If you want to create your own slider, I recommend you to use this library 
https://github.com/mattlawer/MBSliderView
You can easy custom this slider.

Comment: What is concerned of my Question with this link?

Comment: What is concerned of memory management with slider customisation?

Comment: Delete the answer kindly before anyone vote down to you . Thanks

Comment: I've added some info, it could be useful for you.